# How do I setup the Laravel Installer & Laravel Spark Installer's bash PATH?

Tags: bash, laravel, ubuntu, vagrant, laravel-spark

I am struggling with the Laravel & Spark Installers with regard to the bash 'PATH' update step. I have always used Composer to setup my Laravel projects manually.

I am working with Ubuntu 14.04 on a Vagrant Box.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Finally figured it out. The Laravel Installer installs globally but the Spark installer gets installed locally, so you have to add 2 PATH to your OS `.bashrc`.

For me, composer global installed the Laravel installer to `~/.composer/vendor/bin` (When you install the Laravel installer via composer global, it will tell you where it was installed.) and I cloned the Spark installer into `/usr/share/nginx/spark-installer`.

Open your `.bashrc` file:

```
vim ~/.bashrc
```

Add 2 new lines to the bottom (use your paths):

```
# Laravel Installer
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin"

# Spark Installer
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/share/nginx/spark-installer"
```

Reload your `.bashrc`:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: You don't need `export` on these lines. `PATH` is almost certainly already exported and you only need to export a variable once (even if you change its value).

Comment: If /usr/share/nginx/ folder doesn't exist, what should I do ?

Comment: It is the path to the `spark-installer` directory. So wherever you git cloned it.